# Laravel 4 with forge, environment variables issue

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-4, environment-variables, laravel-forge

I'm having trouble using forge and environment variables. When I use `getenv('DB_NAME')` and so further I get connection problem when trying to migrate. When I `var_dump` the values in BaseController.php I've the right values. But still not working. If I instead write the values from the given var_dump in the `database.php` config file I get it working. But why the hell does it not work with getenv when the values are correct, any ideas?

In my BaseController.php:

```
var_dump(getenv('DB_HOST'));
var_dump(getenv('DB_NAME'));
var_dump(getenv('DB_USERNAME'));
var_dump(getenv('DB_PASSWORD'));
```

In my database.php:

```
'host'      => getenv('DB_HOST'),
'database'  => getenv('DB_NAME'),
'username'  => getenv('DB_USERNAME'),
'password'  => getenv('DB_PASSWORD'),
```

With this code I get the error message:

```
[PDOException]                                                                     
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

If I instead write the values I get from my var_dumps in BaseController.php everything works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you set those variables in the panel or edited the .env.php file?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've done pretty much everything. When trying but first I sat those through the panel. And then I've been trying to editing the .env.php file but without result. Everytime the same PDOException when trying to run the migration.

Comment: You cannot edit it manually, it will not work. I already asked Taylor to let us do this, because it's simpler. About your problem: you have to be sure your application is set to production, because .env.php is for production as .env.testing.php is for testing. If your application is somewhow in testing/development/local it will not load that .env.php file.

Comment: Sweet, Is it possible that there's an error because I've edited that file once? I mean is it possible that the file became corrupt in or smth like that because I once edited it manually? The `App::environment()` is set to `production` which you asked for. So that is right.

Comment: It will not really corrupt that file, it just will not load it. If you edit them in Forge again, your file will be overwritten. Pretty odd what's happening there.

Comment: I see. I've tried now to delete and recreate the site with the same values in the environment variables. But still the same issue, have nobody seen this stuff before? It happens to me with every new site I create I thought this would be a good time to research why this is happening. Any more code you want to see to maybe help me out?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59833/discussion-between-murum-and-antonio-carlos-ribeiro).

Comment: Just as a side note, I also have ran into this exact problem, and Taylor was unable to fix it. It's really frustrating, and I hope someone comes up with a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you're env file is called `.env.php` and not `.env.production.php`. I made this mistake, and although having `.env.production.php` will work in app, it won't when using Artisan.

When creating env vars within Forge, if it's for a production environment, be sure to leave the environment field blank, as opposed to explicitly setting it to production.